# Javascript: While loop won't stop - converting units for giving area of a space

Tags: javascript

For some reason this code keeps looping endlessly. The purpose is for converting from square foot or meter to another measurement. I want the code to loop and prompt the user again only if they don't enter in the words 'meter' or 'foot' but instead it loops endlessly and causes chrome to crash. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
while (whichunit !== "meter" || "foot"){
var whichunit = prompt("Would you like to convert from square meter or square foot? Enter meter/foot below");

    if(whichunit == "meter"){
    var unitnum = prompt("What is the price per meter?");
    var matchboxindex = unitnum * 0.0015;
    console.log("The match box index is " + matchboxindex);
}
        else if(whichunit == "foot"){
        var unitnum = prompt("What is the price per foot?");
        var matchboxindex = unitnum *0.0015 * 10.7639;
        console.log("The match box index is " + matchboxindex);
        }
            else {
            console.log("Please enter either foot or meter");
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (whichunit !== "meter" || "foot"){
var whichunit = prompt("Would you like to convert from square meter or square     foot? Enter meter/foot below");
```

The infinite loop is because the condition after '||' (which should be '&') is just ***'foot' which will always evaluate to true***. So just rewrite as:

```
var whichunit = '';
while (whichunit !== "meter" && whichunit !== "foot"){
    whichunit = prompt("Would you like to convert from square meter or square     foot? Enter meter/foot below");
    ...
```

Comment: `(which should be '&&')` . . . not `'&'`   ;)